# Can't Start Apache on on Snow Leopard. "libphp5.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0"

Tags: php, apache-http-server, imagemagick, osx-snow-leopard

To cut a long story short, I was trying to compile and get ImageMagick working on my Mac running Snow Leopard.

One thing led to another and now I am stuck with the following error message when I try to start Apache, which I have tried unsuccessfully to fix for the last two days:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 116 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server:
>   dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib\n  Referenced from:
>   /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so\n  Reason: Incompatible library
>   version: libphp5.so requires version 13.0.0 or later, but
>   libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 9.0.0

My Apache Version is as follows:

> Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) Server built:   Dec  5 2011
>   20:56:38

Output of my Apache error log is as follows:

> [Tue Jan 15 20:46:36 2013] [notice] Digest: done [Tue Jan 15 20:46:36
>   2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
>   DAV/2 PHP/5.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations [Tue Jan 15
>   20:46:41 2013] [notice] child pid 34820 exit signal Segmentation fault
>   (11)

Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow posting the issue to StackOverflow got me thinking on a different track and enabled me to fix it. It turns out when I was building PHP it wasn't generating the `libphp5.so` file. Here's how I solved that:

1. First find the `apxs` path by typing this:

   ```
   which apxs
   ```
2. Then build PHP like so (replace `/usr/sbin/apxs` with the result from `which apxs` in step #1:

   ```
   ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs

   make

   sudo make install
   ```